# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined shapefile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers, shapefile

Right I have seen many threads about this problem but my problem is still unresolved. I have the J query being loaded first at the top of the scripts. Like so:

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" ContentPlaceholderID="ChildContent1" runat="server"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/shapefile.js"></script>

<script src="http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/trunk/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
<script src="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/proj4js/"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/WebForms/map.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dbf.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/stream.js"></script>     
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have two javascript files which use Jquery but only the map.js works with it and $ is defined. However in the shapefile.js when I use $, it is not defined. I am very confused. below is the code from the shapefile.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#SHPError").modal("show");
            });
```

Any ideas what could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

As a practice jQuery should be added as the top most script. That might be a problem here. If OpenLayer is a jQuery library.

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" ContentPlaceholderID="ChildContent1" runat="server">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/shapefile.js"></script>

<script src="http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/trunk/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is included and the request doesn't throw a 404 or another HTTP error (check your console) then it is most likely, that there is a `jQuery` object but not a `$`.

You could try one of the two:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#SHPError").modal("show");
});

// or

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#SHPError").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work I am afraid. The only thing in the console is "$ is not defined"

Comment: Are you 100% sure that jQuery is loaded? Did you check for errors?

Comment: Jquery is loaded because it works for the other JavaScript file (map.js) which uses $

Comment: It is very hard to debug this because there are a myriad of possible reasons. Try doing a jsfiddle and post this here. This would make things much easier. Everything else is guessing.